# Title/author of fantasy novel -- the Puritans visit Ottoman Empire ? Alt. Hist

Tags: story-identification, religion, alternate-history

I'm looking for a female fantasy author who wrote a novel about an alternate reality in which the Puritans always ruled America, and visited the Ottoman Empire, seeking a trade deal. It's a commentary on religion and control, with interesting characters. The author also wrote a fantasy series about a woman with a powerful guitar.

Thanks in advance for helping ;me & my rapidly dwindling memory cells....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for **Gael Baudino's** Water series, consisting of ***O, Greenest Branch***, **The Dove Looked In** and **Branch and Crown**. There are the Puritans of the Righteous States of America and the three African kingdoms of Kaprisha, Kalash, and Khyr. From *Lambda Scifi review*: One plot involves the Righteous States of America's interest in crossing through the kingdoms and over the mountains that isolate them from the rest of Africa in order to confront Napoleon Bonaparte. Another storyline traces an old woman's search for the religion of her youth. A third storyline traces a transgendered eunuch's evolving gender identity and sexuality; and a fourth follows the Prince and self-described "palace stud" as he tries to find meaningful work. She also wrote a fantasy novel with a woman who uses fragments of her magical harp to make a guitar to do heavy metal spells; ***Gossamer Axe***.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's it!!! So grateful to you.  I loved all of these books, but must have lost them in various moves.  Have a wonderful Spring!!! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct.